# .htaccess Pretty URL rewrite inside a folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am trying to rewrite one of my urls to pretty urls but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is what I've tried

Current folder layout

```
-index.php
-/instagram
    -index.php
    -.htaccess
```

Inside the .htaccess I have put this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^instagram/([^/]*)$ /instagram/?username=$1 [L]
```

My goal is to turn this url

```
http://example.com/instagram/?username=test1234
```

into this url

```
http://example.com/instagram/test1234
```

However, when I go to the second url in my browser it gives a 404 not found error. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried `RewriteRule ^instagram/([^/]*)$ /instagram/index.php?username=$1 [L]`  I'm just thinking that you may want to explicitly give it the index.php file, since it won't show anyway

Comment: When I try that I get a 500 internal server error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this code inside `/instagram/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /instagram/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: When this man ^ answers an .htaccess / mod_rewrite question, you can be 99% certain it's right - seems to ninja me quite often too ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind words @CD001